# error Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_REFERER"

Tags: arrays, key, undefined, warnings

error please help

Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_REFERER" in /home/editoral/domains/editoraleader.com.br/public_html/jornal-leader/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/Newspaper.theme#archive on line 43

Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_REFERER" in /home/editoral/domains/editoraleader.com.br/public_html/jornal-leader/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/Newspaper.theme#archive on line 43

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)